# What's the cheapest iPhone I can buy on which I can install WhatsApp?

Tags: iphone, ios, whatsapp.app

I need a temporary iPhone on which I can install WhatsApp in order to keep my conversations, since I will be handing in my current work phone, which is an iPhone, on which I have a lot of WhatsApp conversations. I believe that WhatsApp requires iOS 10 or later to be installed. Which is the cheapest iPhone (presumable the oldest model?) that can run the required iOS version?

Comment: Whatsup is working fine on my iPhone 6.

Comment: But you could download Mactracker and see which iPhone will run OS 10…

Comment: I’d be worried about the potential for backwards (in)compatibility. A 6S is the oldest phone that can run the current iOS

Comment: @Tetsujin then I am lucky to have a 6S plus...

Answer (score 1):

WhatsApp currently supports iOS 10 or newer; and iPhone 5 is the oldest model that runs iOS 10 (Last version it supports is iOS 10.3.4). This should be the cheapest compatible model, if you can find it.